# iOS can't connect localhot

Tags: localhost, networkextension

I create an `http` server in `NEPacketTunnelProvider`. I know that this is an independent Process. However, I can connect to it using `102.168.0.xx:ip` with another device in same wifi but I can't connect using `localhost:ip` in `iOS` safari.

Answer (score 0):

You are only running the server on your physical network interface, not loopback as well.  Try in your server's config making it run on `0.0.0.0` to add the server to all interfaces including `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.0.x`.